# Cannot uninstall MacPorts

Tags: macports

I am trying to uninstall MacPorts using this command :

```
sudo port -fp uninstall installed
```

But I get an error:

```
Error: No ports matched the given expression
```

Port command is functioning though. So I cannot figure out what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

This command only uninstalls the (installed) ports, *not* the MacPorts infrastructure itself. There are instructions for removing Macports [here](http://guide.macports.org/#installing.macports.uninstalling), along with other basics.